# Telegram-bot с постоянным отслеживанием трансляции геопозиции на Python3 + python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, геолокация

Пытаюсь написать телеграм-бота, который будет отслеживать местоположение телефона (боту юзер транслирует геопозицию) и, при попадании в заранее определённую зону координат, бот будет слать какое-то текстовое сообщение. Решил заюзать python-telegram-bot библиотеку + питон3.
Посему вопрос: есть ли разница в реализации методов для обычного "Отправить местоположение" и "трансляция местоположения"? Если есть, то что нужно использовать (просьба ткнуть носом)?
Мой код: https://pastebin.com/r3vMpsx9

`

```
import config
import random
from telegram.ext import *
import requests
import re
import sys
import json
import pprint

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")

def stop(update, context):
    print('Good-bye')
    sys.exit()

def echo(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=update.message.text)

def showMyLoc(update, context):
    print(update.message['location'])

updater = Updater(token=config.TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# ----------- BOT Commands Creation ----------------
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

stop_handler = CommandHandler('stop', stop)
dispatcher.add_handler(stop_handler)

echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo) ### Returns ANY input by user TEXT
dispatcher.add_handler(echo_handler)

location_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.location, showMyLoc) ### Returns ANY input by user TEXT
dispatcher.add_handler(location_handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater.start_polling()
```

`

Пасиб.

P. S.: Доку по библиотеке и АПИ Телеграма читал, но мало что понял (вот такой вот я баран тугой)...

Comment: Как успехи? Меня тоже интересует эта тема)

Answer (score -1):

Не смогу помочь с решением вопроса точно, сам с таким не сталкивался.
Скорее всего - встроенного решения нет, т.к. любой код при запуске - уже отработал, и он не может работать с постоянно меняющейся геолокацией.
Думаю есть возможность решить костыльным путём.
Создать цикл, который каждую 0.1 секунду будет обновлять геоданные, и передавать их обработчику, который будет отслеживать, вошёл ли человек в область действия твоего сообщения.

Есть вещь, с которой я могу попробовать помочь более профессионально, касательно модуля python-telegram-bot. Если в этом ещё есть потребность - пишите